# Swift: Can't push to view controller programatically

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I'm trying to push to different viewcontroller programatically using this code:

```
let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! MenuController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

Here is my setup: I have swift file called: `MenuController` which contains  this code I set the identifier name to: `LoginViewController` I set the class of both `ViewControllers` set to `MenuController`. But whenever I press the button to trigger the event it doesn't do anything.

Here is the rest of my code as requested:

```
import UIKit

class MenuController: UIViewController {

    var thingy = 0

    @IBAction func ThingyBttn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(thingy == 1) {
            print("ok")
        }else{
            print("good")

            let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! MenuController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let ButtonImage = myButton.image(for: .normal),
            let Image = UIImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png"),
            UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(Image) {
            thingy = 1

            print("1")                
        } else {
            thingy = 2

            print("2")
        }   
    }

}
```

I know that everything else with the code works fine because it's printing the message.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? Show the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer I just added the rest of the code.

Comment: The names you have used sound confusing? LoginViewController as MenuController? use the same identifier as the class name and then it's easy. Also prevent force unwrapping with !, it can be quite dangerous

Comment: Some debug advice on debugging: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)`. Check that `self.navigationController` is not nil, if it is, it won't do anything. That could lead to the question: Do you have a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the vc you do the push from inside a navigationController as this

```
self.navigationController?
```

is `nil`  , or do it programmatically

**Edit:**

Replace this

```
let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! MenuController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

with

```
let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! MenuController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController:self) 
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = nav 
nav.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I don't quiet get what you mean can you please show me in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your view controllers are not in `Navigation Stack` thats why its not pushing to next view controller

```
let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “nextvc”) as! nextvc
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController:self) 
UIAppliaction.window!.rootViewController = navigation  
navigation.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```